# Build a boost project using cmake in msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, cmake

I have written a code to read a compressed file directly. I have to build it using Cmake. This is my only source file, uncompress.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>
// cl /EHsc uncompress.cpp

std::vector<char> & readline(std::istream & stream, std::vector<char> & container) {
    char c;
    container.clear();
    while (stream && stream.get(c)) {
        container.push_back(c);
        if (c == '\n') break;
    }
    return container;
}

int main () {
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream cinn(std::cin);
    in.push(boost::iostreams::bzip2_decompressor());
    in.push(cinn);

    std::vector<char> line;
    while (readline(in, line).size() != 0) {
        std::string str(line.begin(), line.end());
        std::cout << "--" << str ;
    }
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt includes

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.9)
project (reader-demo CXX C)

find_package (Boost COMPONENTS iostreams zlib REQUIRED)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

add_executable(reader uncompress.cpp)
target_link_libraries(reader ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

my cmake command is:

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" .
```

This throws the error boost_zlib not found during cmake

> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>                boost_zlib

I have the following zlib library built into all paths are set properly:

[image]

**NOTE** if I change the CMakeLists.txt to this. it works fine. But I can't understand how :/

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.9)
project (reader-demo CXX C)

add_executable(reader uncompress.cpp)
```

it works fine as expected. reader.exe is make and that works fine.

My question is: why is it not able to find boost_zlib the time I mention it in cmake and why is it working fine when I remove the target_link_libraries().

Comment: The libraries you found are static libraries not DLLs. To use the static libraries you need to add `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)` to your CMakeLists.txt file **before** the `find_package(Boost ...)` call. And you should add `-DBOOST_ROOT=<path_to_your_Boost_installation>` to your CMake command line call to make sure Boost is found regardless of a non standard installation directory.

Comment: BTW which version of CMake are you using with Boost 1.67?

Comment: version of my cmake is 3.11.2 @vre

Comment: Did you always deleted the `CMakeCache.txt` file after doing your changes to `CMakeLists.txt`? The values of a Boost search are cached in CMake and you do not reference any boost_zlib related stuff directly in your cpp file. That may be the reason why it works in the second call.

Comment: zlib is not a registered Boost component although the Boost build process for boost_iostreams lib generates a boost_zlib and boost_bzip2 library. So  FindBoost.cmake does not know about these (they are internal).

Comment: thanks @vre set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) was the thing missing there. It worked fine

Answer (score 0):

*Expanding my comments to an answer:*

`zlib` is not a registered `Boost` component although the `Boost` build process for `boost_iostreams` lib generates a `boost_zlib` and `boost_bzip2` library. Both are internally generated and linked to. The CMake module `FindBoost.cmake` that is called when you add `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS iostreams zlib REQUIRED)` to your `CMakeLists.txt` file does not know about these libraries.

- To answer the first part of the question:

  **remove** `zlib` from your `find_package` call.

After doing so delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file because the values of a `Boost` search are cached in `CMake`.

- To answer the second part of the question:

  You removed the `Boost` stuff from the `CMakeLists.txt` but presumably did not delete the `CMakeCache.txt`. It might still contain the necessary `Boost` entries for the compiler/linker and that may be the reason why it works in the second call.

The libraries you showed in the image are the (multithreaded) static libraries **and** the import libraries for the DLLs.

- To use the static libraries

  you need to add `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)` to your CMakeLists.txt file before calling `find_package(Boost ...)`.
- To use the Shared Objects (SO)/Dynamic Link Libraries (DLL)

  you don't need to add anything to your `CMakeLists.txt` file before calling `find_package(Boost ...)`, as dynamic link libraries are chosen by default. But to run the executable the directory that contains the DLLs must be added to the `PATH` environment variable.

**NB:**

Please remove the call to `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})` and add after the definition of your target

```
add_executable(reader uncompress)
target_include_directories(reader PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Note the trailing `S` in the variable name. This variable is assigned a value in the `find_package(Boost ..)` call, the other variable is used to look up the include directory of Boost and is an input to the FindBoost module. Doing so you add the include directories to the target only but not to the global environment.

Finally you should add `-DBOOST_ROOT=<path_to_your_Boost_installation>` to your `CMake` command line call to make sure `Boost` is found regardless of a non standard installation directory.

For extended information about `find_package(Boost ...)` please see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FindBoost.html?highlight=findboost)